# syntax error; unexpected symbol:

Tags: c, undefined-symbol

I'm making a bunch of c/src files, and get:

```
syntax error; unexpected symbol: "EnableUART"
```

It is referenced in a driver.c file and defined in a .src file.
It is XDEF'd correctly,

Here is  the c snippet:

```
int main() { 
EnableUART(0, 9600, 'N');
}
```

Any ideas of why something gives this error?
TYTY

Comment: It would help to have the definition of it, and make sure it's not a declaration.

Comment: (Removing "make" tag, since I don't think it has anything to do with make.)

Answer (score 1):

Where is the EnableUART() defined?  You need to include the header file at the top of your source file like this:

```
#include "library.h"
```

replacing `library.h` with the header file that includes the declaration of EnableUART().

Comment: It is defined in a src file that I already have declared in the header of the file.

Comment: you might want to paste a more significative portion of your program